# Excel: Merging multiple Rows/Columns based on one repeated cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I need to *merge* the information of multiple rows and columns based on a common value for an specific cell.

I guess I can use a macro here, as the problem is I have to *merge* a lot of information, where for some rows some columns are blank and others have information.

The values in the cells I need to use to merge the rows may appear more than once.

I'm adding an image where you can see the structure of the document and part of the list of repeated values for the "Email" column. I examine it with the VLOOKUP function and there are about 3000, while the sheet has about 5000 rows.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls4ZJ.jpg)

[image]

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRHIE.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I can't fully understand you. You have one NGO on each row. On column `D` you have an email and other email in column `O`. Sometimes it is the same, and sometimes is different. Based on that you want to merge something but you are not explaining what.

Comment: I know my explanation can be confusing, sorry! I want to merge all the info  available for each NGO, when the NGO is repeated. For this, I would use the email on column D, because is the most likely field to be common when the NGO  is the same (the name can be slightly different and be the same NGO). The column O shows the repeated emails I found (3000), so the explanation would be there are 3000 NGOs repeated in the file. As the NGOs can have different data at the columns depending the row, I need to merge them! is clear now?

Comment: So you are looking for duplicate NGOs based on the email?

Comment: Yeap, and I want to merge all the info for each NGO into one row

Answer (score 0):

With VBA /Macros:

```vb
Public Sub myDuplicates()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    emailcolumn = 4
    totalcolumns = 12
    merges = 0
    theSymbol = " / "
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastRow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        email1 = wks.Cells(i, emailcolumn)
        For j = i - 1 To 2 Step -1
            email2 = wks.Cells(j, emailcolumn)
            If LCase(email1) = LCase(email2) Then
                For k = 1 To totalcolumns
                    If LCase(Cells(i, k)) <> LCase(Cells(j, k)) Then
                        Cells(j, k) = Cells(j, k) & theSymbol & Cells(i, k)
                    End If
                Next k
                wks.Rows(i).Delete
                j = 1
                merges = merges + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    theMessage = MsgBox("Finished with " & merges & " merges", vbInformation)
End Sub
```

Open VBA/Macros, insert a new module under *ThisWorkbook* and paste this code on the right side.

When two emails are the same, it merges all the **different** fields only. And use `/`to separate them inside the cell.

It supposes your email field is the fourth column. It can be changed using the variable `emailcolumn` and also assumes your max column is 12, also it can be easily changed on variable `totalcolumns`.

Comment: Thank you for your help but didn't work.. only take away 200 rows (it's suppose to take 3000).

Comment: It calculates the number of rows from Column A. The line `lastRow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: It calculates the number of rows from Column A. The line `lastRow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. If there is a blank cell on column A then it starts from then. If you know the number of rows (for example, 3000) then replace that line with `lastRow=3000`and it should work.